# Facebook Like Box displays only if logged in

Tags: facebook

as the title says, I found out my like box not appearing unless I am logged in facebook
Back in the past it was not like this

On some websites, I see the like box showing up even if I am not logged; I checked the code, and what differs from mine is that they have an AppID

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an AppID your Check your application not running in `sandbox`  or development mode

here is a sample of your like button code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: _“not running in `stanbox`”_ – I think you mean “sandbox”, and that is now called “development mode” …